# JaveFX toggle button doesn't return to default after setting background

Tags: javafx

I have the following code in my app

```java
private void showImg(ToggleButton tb) {
    Image img = new Image(getAssociatedImage(tb), tb.getWidth(), tb.getHeight(), false, true, true);
    BackgroundImage bimg = new BackgroundImage(img, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, new BackgroundSize(tb.getWidth(), tb.getHeight(), true, true, true, false));
    Background bkg = new Background(bimg);
    Background old = tb.getBackground();
    tb.setBackground(bkg);
    PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(3));
    pause.setOnFinished(event -> {
        tb.setBackground(old);
    });
    pause.play().
}
```

It mainly does as I've expected, showing the new background img for 3 seconds, but after "restoring" the old background the `ToggleButton` looks and feel different; It doesn't look "metalic" as it used to, clicking on it doesn't make it appear "selected", no hovering reaction.

I'm not sure what I've done wrong here I returned the original background of the button and expected it to go back to "default"

EDIT:
minimal working example

```
public class Test2  extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        ToggleButton root = new ToggleButton();
        root.setPrefHeight(300);
        root.setPrefWidth(300);
        root.setOnAction(event -> {
            Image img = new Image(getClass().getResource("1.png").toExternalForm(), root.getWidth(), root.getHeight(), false, true, true);
            BackgroundImage bimg = new BackgroundImage(img, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, new BackgroundSize(root.getWidth(), root.getHeight(), false, false, true, false));
            Background bkg = new Background(bimg);
            Background old = root.getBackground();
            root.setBackground(bkg);
            PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(3));
            pause.setOnFinished(evt -> {
                root.setBackground(old);
            });
            pause.play();
        });
        Scene scene = new Scene((Parent)root);
        stage.setTitle("Example");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: @kleopatra my mistake I assumed the snippet was reproducible enough

Comment: Default background is defined in css not code.  If you set the background explicitly, it will use that not the default css.  Perhaps if you just set the background to null it will restore the css processing for it (I don’t know, I didn’t try it).